# Can you delete the Humanity icon theme safely?

Tags: themes, delete, icons, cleanup

I'm trying to reduce used space after running disk usage analyser, since I'm using a 40GB SSD. The icons use quite a bit of space! Could I delete those that I don't use, such as humanity? (I use Faenza-Dark)

If it is possible, what would be the best way to this? as when I attempt to remove humanity in the Software Centre it says the software-centre itself must be removed. Similar problems arise with synaptic package manager.

I was wary of just deleting the unused directories in usr/share/icons/.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Well, first switch to an icon theme other than Humanity?

```
System-Preferences->Appearence->Customize->Icons
```

And then maybe remove the package instead of just deleting them:

```
sudo apt-get remove humanity-icon-theme
```

Oh, I'm sorry I didn't read all you wrote. This does remove at least
gnome-themes-ubuntu, humanity-icon-theme, light-themes, software-center,
ubuntu-artwork, ubuntu-desktop, and ubuntu-mono.

Chris

Comment: Thanks for the help Chris. Do you know if I can reinstall just the software-centre exclusively, after its removal? I tried "apt-get install software-center" but the humanity-icon-theme insisted on reinstalling too. Bad times.

Comment: No it will keep installing all of its dependencies.